# How can I use schedule for many different tasks in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-scheduler

I have the schedule which calls everyMinute one type of company, but now I have a company table and different parameters for schedule. For instance: Google - calls every 5 minutes, Twitter - calls every 15 minutes etc.

```
  $schedule->call(function () {
            $service = new Service();
            $companies = Company::all();
            $service->get($companies);
        })->everyMinute();
```

So how can I redo this? Can I do something like this?

```
$companies = Company::all();
  foreach($companies as $company) {
       $schedule->call(function () {
            $service = new Service();
            $service->get($company);
        })->$companyTime();
  }
```

Will it work for every company with own settings?
P.S. I can not check it because It does not work locally. Thank you!

Comment: "It does not work locally."  You mean whole project or cron/scheduling only?

Comment: I mean cron only

Answer (score 0):

If your project works locally, you can check it without a cron set. Just run this command locally in the terminal / console and let it run.

```sh
php artisan schedule:run
```